# Phone won't connect to Raspberry Pi Access Point

Tags: networking, internet, access-point

Is there a way to keep an iPhone connected to a Raspberry Pi Access Point that does not have no internet connectivity?

The phone (iOS) automatically switches connection to a network that has internet, even after manually selecting the RPi AP that has no network connectivity. The only workaround is for me to "forget" my standard internet-access AP so my phone stays connected to the RPi AP.

It may be a new OS feature that auto switches to working internet b/c I did not have to do this a few years back and my phone would remain connected to the RPi AP (not connected to internet).

Comment: So your initial question _Is there a way to make the Raspberry Pi Access Point (no internet) stay connected to my phone?_ is confusingly/reverse worded; you actually mean that you want your iPhone to stay connected to the Raspberry Pi access point. This isn't a Raspberry Pi question, but instead an iPhone question - because the iPhone will be making decisions about which AP to stay connected to: not the Raspberry Pi. You might be better to post on https://apple.stackexchange.com/